# How do I make Ghidra propagate modified functon signatures to other programs in that project?

Tags: ghidra

I have imported several programs to my Ghidra project and retyped a few function parameters in one of them.

Now I am working on a different program, which imports these functions.
However, the imported functions still have their original, unmodified signatures.

How do I tell Ghidra to propagate the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that should work is using the "Capture Function Prototypes" context menu action on the Project Datatype Archive while in the binary that defines those functions, then applying them in the binary that imports them.

Comment: what if function names collide? for example on overloaded operators.

Comment: huh, good question. Aren't those function names typically mangled in some way that encodes type information? Are you just wondering in general, or do you have a concrete case where Ghidra does something unexpected?

Comment: i have a concrete case whith overlaoded functions. apparently ghidra identifies the function types by their unmangled names.
it looks similar to this: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/3952#issuecomment-1026105006

Comment: Sounds like it's worth opening an issue for Ghidra